# Open new workspace in android studio

Tags: android, workspace, android-studio

Can't find the option in Android Studio to open new workspace like in Eclipse.

As I understand, it's going like that:

Project in Android Studio equivalent to workspace in Eclipse.

Module in Android Studio equivalent to project in Eclipse.

Am I right?

Comment: Add an existing project and point to the solutions folder.

Comment: @David post your answer..I am also confused...Module in Android Studio equivalent to project in Eclipse. this statement is true or not?

Answer (score 6):

You are right, When you create new project, it'll tip open new workspace

Answer (score 1):

According to http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Eclipse_FAQ, you are right. The first question in the FAQ says exactly that.

Comment: The link redirects to IntelliJ help. [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/eclipse-faq.html?search=Eclipse#d146447e110) is the new link.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.paste your project to some desired location import or open any the project from your desired location.That desired location will be set your workspace